# jquery ui: google api : including sortables

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have included jquery and jqueryui from google api as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I want to use jquery ui sortable facilities. Do I need to include any more libraries to do so ?

I tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#sortable").sortable();
    });
    </script>
```

but didnt worked for me, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reverse the script references.**

First you need [jQuery](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js) (The Core), then [jQuery UI](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3 jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```